# Sort by longitude and latitude based on starting point

Tags: excel, vba

I converted the physical address to longitude and latitude in Excel. Is there a way to sort by starting point? For example, this is my starting point 42.0932869, -80.1049180, can Excel sort the longitude and latitude of what comes next from the starting point? I am trying to create a walking list of addresses and would like them in order based on starting location.

I am using Excel 365

Starting Point 42.0932869, -80.1049180 then what would be the next address from the list below?

```
42.0923267, -80.1041138
42.0840190, -80.0974670
42.0840500, -80.0967051
42.0935450, -80.1033530
42.0855000, -80.1021200
42.0916309, -80.0989128
42.0846050, -80.1010570
42.0846050, -80.1010570
42.0843432, -80.0993665
42.0924650, -80.1074910
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new column with the value of the distance between points formula and apply sorting on that column:

```
SQRT((lat - 42.0932869)^2 + (lon - -80.1041138)^2)
```

Comment: It does not work. lat and lon are not formula expressions

Comment: I'm not sure what your data looks like but my answer is based on the assumption that for the same point column A has the latitude value stored and column B has the longitude. Then you create column C which is just a formula column with the formula above and sort column C

Comment: Store in C something like:

 `=POWER(POWER(SUM(A1,-42.0932869),2)+POWER(SUM(B1,80.1041138),2),0.5)`

Comment: Yes I have the latitude and longitude in separate columns. When I tried this formula  =POWER(POWER(SUM(A1,-42.0932869),2)+POWER(SUM(B1,80.1041138)‌​,2),0.5) Excel showed the pop up box with the error message "There is a problem with the formula

Comment: Check that the columns labels match what you have, that formula will be applied to columns A and B, check yours are those as well or replace them if needed.

Comment: Yes longitude and latitude are in columns A and B Resoectively

Comment: try this`=SQRT(((A1-42.0932869)^2)+(B1+80.1041138)^2)`